# Cofinite $\sigma$-algebra not a measure space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathfrak{M}$ be the set of all sets $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that either $A$ or $A^c$ (the complement of $A$) are countable. Define

$$\mu(A) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } A^c \text{ is at most countable} \\
0 & \text{ if } A \text{ is at most countable}
\end{cases}$$

Show $\mathfrak{M}$ is a $\sigma-$algebra.

Now show that $(\mathbb{R}, \mathfrak{M}, \mu)$ is a measure space.

The first part is simple. I'm a bit confused as to why this triple is indeed a measure space. Namely, Let $\{A_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $A_i \in \mathfrak{M}$ and $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ for $i \neq j$. Then,

$$\mu\left(\coprod_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i\right) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } A_i \text{ is countable for all } i \in \mathbb{N} \\
1 & \text{ if } A_{i_0} \text{ is uncountable for some } i_0\\
\end{cases}$$

But, $$\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mu(A_i) =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } A_i \text{ is countable for all } i \in \mathbb{N} \\
|J| & \text{ if } \{A_j\}_{j \in J} \text{ is uncountable for some } J \subset \mathbb{N} \\
\end{cases}. $$

How then is it possible for $\mu$ to be a measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the fact that disjoint implies that you cannot have more than one non-zero term in that sum. Your assumption on uncountability is not actually quite equivalent, and when we reprhase it more carefully, the ostensible problem disappears, you have

> $$\mu\left(\coprod_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right) =
> \begin{cases} 0 & \forall i \;|A_i|\le \aleph_0  \\
> 1 & \exists i \;|A_i^c|\le\aleph_0\end{cases}.$$

as you say, but

$$\mu\left(\coprod_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right)= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(A_i)$$

**does** hold because if one of the $A_i$ has $|A_i^c|\le\aleph_0$ and they are all disjoint, then $A_j\subseteq A_i^c$ when $i\ne j$ hence $|A_j|\le|A_i^c|\le\aleph_0$, hence $\mu(A_j)=0$.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. I wasn't realizing that disjointness fixed this easily.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter  no problem:  easy thing to miss. :-)

Comment: I believe that in your answer where you wrote: 
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(A_i)= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(A_i)$$ you meant  
$$\mu\left(\coprod_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(A_i)$$.

Comment: @Ramiro Thanks, yes, I'll edit. :)